# JUnit5 - ExpectedException.expectCause() equivalent

Tags: junit5

Is there a JUnit5 equivalent of `ExpectedException.expectCause()` (JUnit4)?
  https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html#expectCause(org.hamcrest.Matcher)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
public class ExpectedExceptionTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldThrow() {
        IOException exc = Assertions.assertThrows(IOException.class, this::throwing);
        Assertions.assertEquals("root cause", exc.getCause().getMessage());
    }

    private void throwing() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException(new IllegalStateException("root cause"));
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer AssertJ which has very descriptive [exception assertions](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#exception-assertion).

Comment: Without more information in the JUnit5 documentation, this is what I have finally done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We replaced the `ExpectedException.expectCause()` with:

```
ThrowableAssert.ThrowingCallable throwingCallable  = () -> someClass.methodWhichThrowAnException(someData);
assertThatThrownBy(throwingCallable).hasCauseInstanceOf(SomeException.class);
```